# Jeep Wrangler 2015: What is this part under the hood? And, now that I burned plastic on it, should I replace it?

Tags: jeep, part-identification, wrangler

I apparently dropped a small piece of vinyl hose in the passenger side engine bay, which ended up resting on, and then melting on the pictured part when I turned the engine on. I removed the hose when I noticed the smoke. The smoke was from the hose, not the part. The car otherwise works fine, but I don't recognize this part. So, I don't know if I should be worried or plan to repair it.

[image: Picture of Unknown Part]

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 2):

It is an oxygen sensor (lambda sensor).
Nothing to worry about.

Comment: Yup. Don’t need to do anything here. It may smell bad for an hour or so. Absolutely nothing to worry about.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a sensor on the exhaust manifold. Try to scrape off the plastic with a knife (to get rid of the smell), the sensor will be fine.